# How to keep coffeescript file and its compiled version in different folders?

Tags: compiler-construction, coffeescript

I want my file/foder structure be clean on my website. So I don't want coffescript file be in the same folder as its compiled version.

While developing I'm using --watch key of compiler. I used this command before

```
coffee -cw ./ ./
```

which worked fine recursively for all coffeescript files when launching this from root of the website. But there is one problem - **it puts compiled files in the same folder**, which I try to avoid.

Is it possible to say to the compile - "please compile every coffeescript file and put compiled version in the parent folder"?

**Update:**

OK. A little bit of a clarification here. I.e. I have this folder structure

```
app
  |- css
  |- images
  |- js
      |- coffee
      |- libs
      |- controllers
               |- coffee
      |- services
               |- coffee
               |- loggers
                      |- coffee
```

As you can guessed I want to store all my coffeescript files inside `coffee` folders, but compile them into the parent folder. E.g. I want to add one more logger, then I add `newLogger.coffee` inside *app/js/services/loggers/coffee* and compiler compiles it and put `newLogger.js` inside *app/js/services/loggers*.

I can use this command inside each `coffee` folder

```
 coffee -cw -o ../ ./
```

So, in this case with 4 `coffee` folders I have 4 compiler instances running for each of them. Can I replace them with one instance?

Comment: @user1737909 which one?

Comment: I love Brunch, it's soooo great. But you could use Yeoman also, or a simple "pipeline tool" like grunt (upon which yeoman is built).

Comment: @user1737909 From what I learned so far, yeoman does not provide convenient solution for my problem. I've found some problems and complains in google about yeoman+coffeescript.

Comment: I never used yeoman, i'm afraid

Comment: You can do it with [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) task manager. With grunt you can specify any folder structure you want to maintain. You can also add task to [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) all your js files after compilation. Grunt is very useful for development, because it can watch your source files and recompile them after every change.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Post an answer please, for now it seems most useful advice.

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov Unfortunately, I don't have a good example of gruntfile and I don't have enough time to write one myself. We're using grunt in our project, but our usecase is slightly different from yours.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I understand, but still your suggestion is the best so far. Just put link to grunt site in answer, I'll give you 50 reputation if there will be no better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) task manager. With grunt you can specify any folder structure you want to maintain.

You can also add task to [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) all your js files after compilation.

Grunt is very useful for development, because it can watch your source files and recompile them after every change.

We're using it right now in our project to manage our front-end. Our task include:

- Compilation of `.coffee`, `.jade` and `.less` files.
- Concatenation of resulting `.js` and `.css` files.
- Minification and uglification of concatenated files.
- Deploying to Amazon S3.

Here's the example of `gruntfile.coffee` which compiles, concatenates uglifies and deploys all `.coffee` files from `assets/js/` directory: https://gist.github.com/lbeschastny/5716323 (haven't tested it yet).

You can find more examples with the detailed instruction how to run them in [getting started section of grunt site](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

Answer (score 4):

from coffeescript docs:

> Compile a directory tree of .coffee files in src into a parallel tree
>   of .js files in lib:

```
coffee --compile --output lib/ src/
```

Answer (score 1):

see this link 
http://coffeescript.org/#usage

it says -o, --output [DIR]   Write out all compiled JavaScript files into the specified directory. Use in conjunction with --compile or --watch.

hope it helps. :)

Comment: I don't believe that you read my question :) Of course I know that, and use --compile and --watch keys. Just for one folder, but I need for all folders recursively.

Answer (score 0):

you need to complete separate coffeescripts folder structure and compiled folder structure.

```
app
  |- css  
  |- images
  |- js
      |- libs
      |- controllers
      |- services
               |- loggers
```

This one will contain all coffee scripts.

```
app-src
  |- js
      |- controllers
      |- services
               |- loggers
```

Then compile at the root folder of both app and app-src `coffee -cw app app-src`.

Answer (score 0):

> So, in this case with 4 coffee folders I have 4 compiler instances
>   running for each of them. Can I replace them with one instance?

No.  The Coffee compiler only supports changing the prefix of the directory path of the source to generate the output path; it does not support adding a suffix like `../` to it.

The `coffee` command line utility is written in Coffescript and the source is [very well documented](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html), so you could modify it yourself to add the option you want.  Easiest would be to simply change the meaning of the `--output` option.  (Although then you wouldn't be able to share the changes with the world, which would be a shame.)  I think all you need to do is change:

```
  dir       = if opts.output then path.join opts.output, baseDir else srcDir
```

to:

```
  dir       = if opts.output then path.join baseDir, opts.output else srcDir
```

In the `outputPath()` function: [command.coffee line 261](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/63bc7fe3543363071d3fbb81f34b70d097a4ed91/src/command.coffee)